# Mac OSX open With function not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, macos, import

i want to open an Image file in my app using Open With function but it is not opening 
here is the xcode settings

[xcode Plist settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci628.png)

and here is the code of appdelegate

[App Delegate Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMMm7.png)

```
@property (assign) NSMutableArray *_allFiles ;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    if (_allFiles.count >0)
    {
        [self openFiles:[_allFiles objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.homeViewController.view];
    self.homeViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}

- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename {
    [self application:theApplication openFiles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filename]];
    [self.homeViewController ShowAlert:filename];
    NSLog(@"====%@",filename);
    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {
    if(!_allFiles)
    {
        _allFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    }
    [_allFiles addObjectsFromArray:filenames];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a file from your 'Supported Files' folder you have to say:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/Resources/YourFile.extension"]];
```

Replace `YourApp.app` with your app.
Replace `YourFile.extension` with your Image.

Note:
This will only work if your application is located in your application folder.
If it's not, you have to change the path or put your app there.

Comment: NO mate i want to open image files in my app with the help of OPEN WITH function